# How to use a variable of controller in view for a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie to RoR. I have an instance variable in controller and want to use that variable in view in a javascript function. Here is the demo code:

Controller code:

```
class SayController < ApplicationController
  def hello
    @hello = 'hello'
  end
end
```

View code:

```
<h1>Hello View</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" ></script>

<script>
alert('test')
alert(<%= @hello %>)
</script>
```

The problem is that the first alert box ('test') comes whereas the second one doesn't come. How do I fix this?

Comment: try the `gon` gem, its useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT LIKE THIS:

```
<h1>Hello View</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" ></script>

<script>
alert('test')
alert('<%= @hello %>')
</script>
```

Every alert should have quotes.